# SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY performs differently

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, ssms

Another problem here with `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` returning `NULL`

The situation is the following: I have a virtual machine running Windows Server 2012R2 with SQL Server 2012. On my own machine I am using same SQL Server and Windows 8.1

Executing the following query in Management Studio:

```
INSERT INTO [DB1].[Extract].[Log]([Package], [StartTime])
VALUES ('Bla', GETDATE())

SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS 'Identity';
```

returns the identity of the row inserted on my PC **BUT** in the virtual machine returns `NULL` (still inserts the row), therefore an SSIS package cannot execute.

What the hell is going on? Could it be some additional permissions to the database?

I cannot miss to say *"It works on my machine!"* :)

Comment: Just to be sure ... DB1.Extract.Log has an identity column defined on the virtual machine?

Comment: To be clear - does running the SSIS package against your local machine (with a dummy/suitably reduced copy of the real database) also work, or does it also fail?

Comment: Yes it does work. Everything works on my machine :D

Comment: BTW, you should start using the output clause instead. Scope_identity has a problem with parralleism that output does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SCOPE_IDENTITY()` will return null if the table being inserted into doesn't have an `IDENTITY` column - so it is worth double checking your schema on the machine where it is not working to ensure that there is, in fact, an `IDENTITY` column.

Comment: Okay thats really strange. I do have added an IDENTITY column to the VM database and it works! But I DO NOT have an identity column in the database on my PC and it still works. (triple checked it). That's odd...

Comment: Any ideas about that guys?

Comment: @Pepys - You're getting the value for the last thing that you inserted into that *did* have an `IDENTITY`...

Answer (score 0):

Did you do a restore of the database between servers or just copy the data in to a new table on one server via a query or SSIS package ?

Comment: I just copied it. I do everything on my own pc before putting into the virtual machine.